# Should we compare null value with known value?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, missing-data, imputation

I have a binary classification problem and need to prepare the data for model training. There are two classes, duplicate, and nonduplicate. Assume two records of the data is like

| Id | Name | Phone | Email | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | Mick | 12345 | m@m.com | London |
| A2 | Mick | 12345 | null | London |

It seems that these two records are duplicates. I need to turn them in one record and assign each feature a binary value of 1 if their values match; otherwise, a 0 as follows

| Id1 | Id2 | Name | Phone | Email | City | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A2 | 1 | 1 | ? | 1 | 1 |

As the first table shows, we have a missing value for the email in the second row. I know I cannot compare a known value with a missing one. The question is, what is the best practice in this case?

**Note: The number of missing values is high in my dataset, and I cannot drop them.**

I tried to put 0, but I know it introduces bias in the dataset.

Answer (score -2):

you can drop the records wit the null values

to do this use

Pandas dropna()

Comment: As mentioned in the question, there are many null values. If I remove them, nothing will remain.